# Cake php SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I got this error while adding users.

I have a view **adduser.ctp**

and in the User controller I have this function

```
 public function addUser() {
    $userGroups = $this->UserGroup->getGroups();
    unset($userGroups[1]);
    unset($userGroups[2]);
    $this->set('userGroups', $userGroups);
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $this->User->set($this->data);
        if ($this->User->AddEditValidate()) {
            $this->request->data['User']['email_verified'] = 1;
            $this->request->data['User']['active'] = 2;
            $this->request->data['User']['parent_id'] = $this->Session->read('logged_client_id');
            $salt = $this->UserAuth->makeSalt();
            $this->request->data['User']['salt'] = $salt;
            $this->request->data['User']['temp_password'] = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
            $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $this->UserAuth->makePassword($this->request->data['User']['password'], $salt);
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data, false)) {
                $this->sendLoginEmail($this->request->data['User']);
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user is successfully added'), 'success_flash');
                $this->redirect('/clientUsers/' . $this->Session->read('logged_client_id'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Problem in saving user information'), 'error_flash');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in User model I validate by the following function

```
function AddEditValidate() {
    $validate1 = array(
        "user_group_id" => array(
            'rule' => array('comparison', '!=', 0),
            'message' => 'Please select group'),
        'first_name' => array(
            'mustNotEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter first name'),
            'custom' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumericSpace',
                'message' => 'First name should be alphnumeric')
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'mustNotEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'on' => 'create',
                'message' => 'Please enter last name'),
            'custom' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumericSpace',
                'message' => 'Last name should be alphnumeric')
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'mustNotEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter email',
                'last' => true),
            'mustBeEmail' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                'message' => 'Please enter valid email',
                'last' => true),
            'mustUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isEmailUnique',
                'message' => 'This email is already registered',
            )
        ),
        'oldpassword' => array(
            'mustNotEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter old password',
                'last' => true),
            'mustMatch' => array(
                'rule' => array('verifyOldPass'),
                'message' => 'Please enter correct old password'),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'mustNotEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter password',
                'on' => 'create',
                'last' => true),
            'complex' => array(
                'rule' => array('complexPassword'),
                'message' => 'Password should be six characters long, which should have minimum one alphabet, one number and one special character',
            ),
        ),
        'captcha' => array(
            'mustMatch' => array(
                'rule' => array('recaptchaValidate'),
                'message' => ''),
        )
    );
    $this->validate = $validate1;
    return $this->validates();
}
```

Its gives me error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'AddEditValidate' at line 1
>
> SQL Query: AddEditValidate

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I know this question asked many times but it will not resolved my problem. In user controller the function is   if ($this->User->AddEditValidate()) {} even i try   if ($this->User->AddEditValidatee()) {} but it gives me the same error. Here in the question i enter AddEditValidatee its is mistake. i know it should be AddEditValidate.

Comment: check spelling use AddEditValidate not AddEditValidatee

Comment: use $this->request->data not $this->data , edit your question for better understanding so that others can help

Comment: @Abhishek $this->request->data does not solve my problem and i edit the question.

Comment: set the function to public and make it lowercase: `public function addEditValidate`

Comment: Can you post also the custom validation methods. this error comes from DB, so it will be one of those: `isEmailUnique` or `verifyOldPass`, perhaps even `recaptchaValidate` if you use DB for verification

Comment: I would bet my money on your model filename not following conventions. This would mean that cake would assume an empty one and of course never see your function. Add something that will cause a fatal error (a missing `;` or a typo) and see if you get a php fatal error. If not your file isn't read.

Answer (score 0):

*Database colum names are not quoted in version 3.0. You are using SQL keywords in your field names. If you cannot rename your columns, you should enable identifier quoting.*

From [book.cakephp.org](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#identifier-quoting):

```
$conn->driver()->autoQuoting(true);
```

> By default CakePHP does not quote identifiers in generated SQL queries. The reason for this is identifier quoting has a few drawbacks:
>
> - Performance overhead - Quoting identifiers is much slower and complex than not doing it.
> - Not necessary in most cases - In non-legacy databases that follow CakePHP’s conventions there is no reason to quote identifiers.
>
> If you are using a legacy schema that requires identifier quoting you can enable it using the quoteIdentifiers setting in your Configuration. You can also enable this feature at runtime:
>
> When enabled, identifier quoting will cause additional query traversal that converts all identifiers into IdentifierExpression objects.

Comment: Don't link to external sites without explaining what to do here in the answer. If the link breaks, your comments will be worthless.

Comment: While this states what the problem may be, you have not provided an actual solution.  This is better suited as a comment, which you can do with additional reputation.  If you can, `edit` your response to provide a clear self-sufficient solution.  If you cannot, SO will likely delete this as "Not an Answer".